# Cómo integrar Opentable widget en HTML

Tags: html, widget

He leído, la info de cómo integrar este widget a mi website

[Documentación de opentable](https://www.opentable.com.mx/widget/reservation/preview?rid=192676&language=es-MX&domainId=6&countryCode=MX)

pero veo que simplemente la documentación nos da un script

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//www.opentable.com.mx/widget/reservation/loader?rid=192676&type=standard&theme=standard&iframe=true&domain=commx&lang=es-MX&newtab=false&ot_source=Restaurant%20website'></script>
```

pero no menciona si hay que agregar algún div o ejecutar algo

quisiera saber si la comunidad lo ha usado o implementado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado y encontrado que para integrar el widget a tu HTML, es simplemente, pegar la linea del script en el espacio de HTML que hayas asignado